# Is it possible to deserialize xml to List object using .net provided serialization attributes?

Tags: c#, serialization, list

I have xml input which looks like (simplified version used for example):

```
<Student>
<Subject> History </Subject>
<Subject> English </Subject>
</Student>
```

Is there a way to get the above xml deserialized to a object whose class looks like:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Student", Namespace="")]
class Student
{
  public Student()
  {
    Subject = new List<string>();
  }

  public List<string> Subject {get;set;}

}
```

Note I am trying to figure out if this can be done without having to implement IXmlSerializable interface, and I want to use a list to store the **Subject** values (not a string [] which I know is possible is I use the XmlElement attribute).

Comment: It is possible, are you running into errors?

Comment: brb, NetDataContractSerializer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decorate the Subject property with the [XmlArrayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute.aspx).

```
[XmlArray]
public List<string> Subject { get; set; }
```

---

If you need to omit the Subject element and have the Subject entries directly below Student, you can simply use the [XmlElement] attribute:

```
[XmlElement]
public List<string> Subject { get; set; }
```

Serializing this with the Student class produces output similar to this:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>
<Student xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"
    xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">
    <Subject>History</Subject>
    <Subject>English</Subject>
</Student>"
```

Comment: Can you still use a list for this?  I thought it throws an error unless it is serializing to an array.

Comment: Actually you are right, "You can also apply it to collections and fields that return an ArrayList or any field that returns an object that implements the IEnumerable interface." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute.aspx

Comment: According to the documentation, it works with anything that implements IEnumerable. IIRC, this is correct, but it's been a while...

Comment: it doesn't work with XmlArray attribute.. i am guessing for now will just change this to an array and decorate the field with XmlElement attribute...

Comment: Yes, it *does* work (I just checked), but I've edited my answer to include more options.

Comment: +1 for the XmlElement attribute.  That worked in my environment.  FWIW, the XmlArray attribute didn't work for me either.

Comment: Thanks Mark.. using XmlElement does work on the LIST.. I thought I had tried that before, and was not getting it to work.. must be doing something else wrong..